# Is it possible to write an arara rule which uses a bash script?

Tags: arara

I've written a shell script to convert some of my files to different formats for use in my LaTeX files.  Is it possible to write an `arara` rule which can use my shell scripts?

**EDIT**

I should note:  the script is loaded through my bash `profile` file where it's defined along the lines

```
myscript () { <script contents> }
```

In other words, the script does not exist as an executable residing in some directory.

Comment: I'm a little confused... I don't see how your first and last sentences can be true at the same time. Could you clarify?

Comment: @cmhughes Perhaps I'm using the wrong language?  In my bash profile I define a number of *functions* which are callable from the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this can certainly be done. Thanks to [Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) ([`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) creator) for his help on this one :)

Let's say that your `.bashrc` contains the following

```bsh
function hello() {
   echo "Hello, $0!"
}

export -f hello
```

Note the use of `export` to make the `hello` function available from the command line.

We can then make our [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) rule to contain the line

```bsh
- <arara> bash -i -c hello @{name}
```

Note the use of the `i` and `c` flags. The rule can then be used either as

```bsh
% arara: hello
```

or

```bsh
% arara: hello: {name: Ellett}
```

## `hello.yaml`

```bsh
!config
# Hello world
# author: Chris Hughes, Paulo Cereda
# last edited by: cmh, June 14th 2013
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
#
# % arara: hello
# % arara: hello: {name: A.Ellett}
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following
#
#   hello
# or
#   hello A.Ellett
#
identifier: hello
name: hello
commands: 
- <arara> bash -i -c hello @{name}
arguments: 
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.name}
  default: "world"
```

## `myfile.tex`

```
% arara: hello
% arara: hello: {name: Ellett}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

And here's the output from `arara -v myfile.tex`

```bsh
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running hello... 

Hello, world!
Status: SUCCESS

Running hello... 

Hello, Ellett!
Status: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I've copied your example exactly and I when I run it I get `bash: no job control in this shell` following by `Hello,` followed by `Status: SUCCESS`.  Notice that nothing followed `Hello,`; the line was just terminated.  I'm doing this on Mac OS X.  Is there something special I have to do there?

Comment: Two things: (1) if I got rid of the `-i` switch things worked.  (2) I'd been using `$*` instead of `$0`.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can make a suggestion for how to get this to work if the bash command takes uses `$*` instead of `$0`.

Comment: @A.Ellett I'll look into it :)

Comment: Does this need to be updated? I needed to switch to `command: ...` rather than `commands:\n- ...`

Comment: An adaptation for `arara 4.0` can be found at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341475/36296

Answer (score 7):

In the next version of TeXlive there will be [TrY](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/try), that is something similar to `arara`, but simpler. It uses simple bash commands into the TeX comments.

The main use of `TrY` is to make explicit in the document the list of commands needed to compile it, something like this:

```tex
%
%$ xetex -shell-escape filename.tex 
%$ bibtex -min-crossref=3 filename.aux
%$ xetex -shell-escape filename.tex
%$ xetex -shell-escape filename.tex
%
```

but you can call your script from the comments in the same way:

```tex
%
%$ ./myscript $0
%$ pdftex $0
%
```

where `$0` is a placeholder standing for the parameter "this document".

You can also put a script into the comment:

```tex
%
%$ while [ $a -le "$LIMIT" ]
%$ do
%$   a=$(($a+1))
%$   if [ "$a" -eq 3 ] || [ "$a" -eq 11 ]
%$   then
%$     continue
%$   fi
%$   echo -n "$a "
%$ done
%
%$ pdftex $0
%
```

(the script is only an example and has not a particular function or meaning).

Then you have to compile the document in the obvious way:

```bsh
$ try mydocument.tex
```

Comment: I'll look forward to trying this out.

Comment: Please allow me to wrote feedback to your answer. `TrY` is really a nice tool, however I am completely disagree with the statement: *but simpler* -- what is simpler than `arara: pdflatex` -- although I see some benefits of `TrY`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel `TrY` has not rules, directives, and so on. `texdoc arara` gives a document 137 pages long; the full manual of `TrY` can be two pages long or so.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I have to agree with Marco. In addition to his comments, note that `arara` is a cross-platform tool; is the same true `TrY`?

Comment: @cmhughes No. `TrY` is written for linux and works on linux. Arithmetic is not agreee with Marco: 2 pages is a number much lesser than 137.

Comment: @JeanBaldraque: I agree -- 2 pages against 137 pages (the new version is longer) is a statement ;-)--It's the price for such a tool.