# Arara rule for log file scraping

Tags: auxiliary-files, kile, arara

Is there a script or [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) rule that does log file scraping for messages about bad boxes, warnings, and obvious rerun messages and outputs this to stdout? It doesn't need to be perfect. I am looking to replace what [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) does at the end of "build" operations since I am using the `arara` clean rule to delete the log file which prevents Kile from scraping it.

Comment: I have an idea, I'll try to write an answer tomorrow. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda is it tomorrow yet?

Comment: I was travelling these days, I'm writing an answer right now. `:)`

Comment: @DanielE.Shub In Brazilian Portuguese, tomorrow means "the next week". ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Hey, I'll write a proper defense... "tomorrow". `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As always, egreg has a great alternative solution for my crazy idea (kept at the bottom of this update, for historical reasons). `:)`

There's a tool named `texloganalyser` [image: Rule Britannia!] (gotta love the spelling!) which might help us. It's shipped in TeX Live, so a quick `texdoc texloganalyser` (which redirects us to a `perldoc texloganalyser`) gives us all the flags we need:

```
-e: displays the end of the log, about the TeX's memory.
-f: outputs the LaTeX Font Infos warnings and calculations.
-h: outputs only warnings about horizontal boxes.
-i: displays 'images' (pdf, [e]ps, png, jpg) used.
-o: outputs only warnings about overfull boxes.
-p: outputs the LaTeX Packages infos and warnings.
-r: displays warnings about references (missing or
multiply-defined).
-s: displays .sty and .cls files used.
-t: displays .tex files used. This option is very useful when you parse
logs of master files, to know in which file to look to correct
errors/warnings.
-u: outputs only warnings about underfull boxes.
-v: outputs only warnings about vertical boxes.
-w: displays all TeX, LaTeX and font Warnings.
```

So it's actually a matter of wrapping `texloganalyser` as an `arara` rule!

```
identifier: texloganalyser
name: TeX Log Analyser
commands: 
- <arara> texloganalyser @{ overfull } @{ underfull } "@{ getBasename(file) }.log"
arguments:
- identifier: overfull
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue(parameters.overfull, "-o") }
- identifier: underfull
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue(parameters.underfull, "-o") }
```

So we can have:

```
% arara: texloganalyser
% arara: texloganalyser: { overfull: yes }
% arara: texloganalyser: { underfull: yes }
% arara: texloganalyser: { overfull: yes, underfull: yes }
```

Again, untested. `:)`

---

I'm not sure if the following solution is actually good, but it's the only one I could think of. `:)` Sadly, `arara` per se has no built-in features for file scrapping, so I think we might need to do some dirty trick in the terminal.

This wacky idea of mine is based on using bash scripts in `arara` (cf. [Is it possible to write an arara rule which uses a bash script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119206/is-it-possible-to-write-an-arara-rule-which-uses-a-bash-script)). Sadly we have a OS-specific trick, and I have no idea how to mimic such behaviour on Windows. Anyway.

I was thinking of a script like this one:

```bsh
function lookuplog() {
    log="$1"
    text="$2"
    output=$(grep "$text" "$log")
    status=$?
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$output"
    else
        echo "Nothing suspicious found."
    fi
}
```

I thought at first, "Hey, let's use `grep` directly", but since its exit code is tied with the number of occurrences found, we might have some problems! That's why I decided to tie `grep` inside of a script which ensures the exit code is always zero and it won't interfere in `arara`'s workflow.

The script we just wrote checks occurrences of certain keywords in the `.log` file. For example,

```
I like ducks!\bye
```

If we run `lookuplog` on the generated `.log` file looking for underfull boxes, this is our output:

```
paulo@alexandria ~$ lookuplog ducks.log "Underfull"
Nothing suspicious found.
```

Now, let's check this file, courtesy of David Carlisle:

```
\hbox to 3in{a}\bye
```

If we run our script, things are quite different:

```
paulo@alexandria ~$ lookuplog mallard.log "Underfull"
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1
```

Yay! Wait a minute, we had an underfull box. `:)`

Now, it's just a matter of wrapping this script inside an `arara` rule. `:)`

```
identifier: lookup
name: LookUp
commands: 
- <arara> bash -i -c lookuplog "@{ getBasename(file) }.log" "Underfull"
- <arara> bash -i -c lookuplog "@{ getBasename(file) }.log" "Overfull"
arguments: []
```

Of course, we need to go on `verbose` mode in order to see what's going on. `:)`

If bad boxes are unacceptable, we could change the script to actually return a non-zero value if they are found - that way, `arara` will stop at a mere sign of a bad box. `:)`

You could wrap all these commands in a single rule, or even create additional rules for overfull or underfull boxes. In fact, note that the `lookuplog` file is just `grep` under the hood, so you can search everything. `:)`

There we go, totally untested, so I'm hoping for the best. `:)`

Comment: I am very impressed but wouldn't it probably be easier to have a peek in the `.log` file with an editor?

Comment: @Yiannis: Agreed. `:)` But we do love to complicate things, don't we? `:)`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I disagree. It is much easier for the computer search the log file for a particular term than it is to read the log file (especially if someone has already written the rule).

Comment: It was really `texloganalyser` that I was looking for, but your `arara` rule is a lot cleaner than mine would have been.

Comment: +1 awesome Paulo! will this be part of the next `arara` release? :)

Comment: You too.... Ah.... Me too!! We like the same thing per than one post.... Helping community, great post...

Comment: I just wanted to mention that texloganalyzer does *not* show errors, only warnings. I had cooked up a similar solution with latexmk, then found out about this.