# What options to use with pdflatex and when

Tags: compiling

Reading this question [arara: show warnings only in the last compilation step](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133613/arara-show-warnings-only-in-the-last-compilation-step) made me realize that I can probably save some compile time by changing the options I use with `pdflatex`. For a "typical" LaTeX file that requires a processing chain like `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` what options (e.g., synctex, draftmode, halt-on-error), should I include with `pdflatex` and when?

Comment: `draftmode` saves you from writing the PDF file, so it *could* be used in the preliminary steps; conversely, `synctex=1` writes useless files during the preliminary steps and it makes sense to use it only for the final run.

Comment: I think one key thing is what I ask in the edited part of my question: can the compilation time be reduced by telling arara to run pdftex only once and only perform successive runs if they are really needed (for instance to correct cross-references) maybe by reading the contents of the aux file or the log?

Comment: I think I am finally able to provide a real answer to both questions (the linked one and this one), but sadly I need to finish my user manual first. I believe it's quite unfair to write about an unreleased version, although it is just a matter of time for it to hit CTAN. Better safe than sorry, I think. The `4.0` version hopefully will provide a better compilation workflow with the inclusion of conditionals; besides, rules can now incorporate more complex tasks, so even if the default ones cannot satisfy one's workflow, I'm sure we will be able to accomplish such task by writing our own rule.

Comment: @petobens and @StrongBad: https://github.com/cereda/arara/wiki/New-feature-highlights-in-4.0 Maybe this simple text could be useful for some hints on what `4.0` is expected to have. Since this version does a huge qualitative jump from `3.0`, it needs a complete user manual. That's what's giving me migraines. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I've been following arara development on github and I'me eager to try the new version. I''ll try today or tomorrow to build from source and see if I can use the examples in your link to use conditionals in order to minimize the number of runs. Do you have an idea regarding when the full user manual will be finished?

Comment: @petobens: I'm trying very hard, but it's quite complicated at the moment (lots of other stuff to do, including my PhD). I'll try to reorganize my schedule and see if I can work on the manual as fast as I can. I probably cannot make into the TL2015 official release, but I believe `4.0` will at least hit the update schedule this year. I'll work on it.

Comment: @petobens: We have a Gitter chatroom, if you need a compiled version, just ping me, I'll be glad to provide you all the necessary files to run and test the new `4.0` version. `:)`

Comment: Thanks @PauloCereda. If I cannot build it myself tomorrow I''ll send you a chat. (thank you for creating arara, I think it is awesome).

Comment: @egreg Looks like the answer to me here: could you convert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-draftmode` in the initial runs of LaTeX, so  everything is done, including writing on auxiliary files, except writing the PDF file. On the other hand `-synctex=1` makes sense only in the last run, saving you from uselessly write and compress a file that can be quite big.

Setting this up for `arara` is easy:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
```

I should add that my workflow is usually just running `pdflatex`, with the occasional run of BibTeX/Biber in order to resolve citations. I understand, though, that some citation styles almost require citations to be resolved as soon as possible (I'm thinking to styles with citations as footnotes). In general there is no need that citations and cross-references are perfect each time `pdflatex` is run and the PDF file viewed.