# use latexmk with jobname option for compilation and rubber for log parsing

Tags: compiling, latexmk, rubber

I use following command for compiling, so all files created during compilation is stored under build_files:

```
latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname=./build_files/thesis thesis.tex
```

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10558/use-latexmk-to-filter-the-log-file) I've found that parsing log file can be done using following rubber commands:

```
rubber-info --check thesis.tex
rubber-info --boxes thesis.tex
```

Problem is that this is working only if all build files is in the same directory as *.tex files. I've tried also following:

```
rubber-info --check ./build_files/thesis
rubber-info --check ./build_files/thesis.tex
rubber-info --check ./build_files/thesis.log
```

But all of them gives me errors.

How can I parse log file contained under ./build_files?

PS: If it is possible to avoid using rubber and there is some better approach please let me know.

PPS: I'm using Linux but multi platform solution would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: How about using https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any ? 1) To keep your directory clean, it places all the auxiliary files in a subfolder and 2) you get beautiful summaries of errors and warnings in different file formats (plain text, pdf, markdown etc.) P.S. it is always nice to see your icon :)

Comment: You can use arara with a custom rule for checking the log file: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131728/arara-rule-for-log-file-scraping

Comment: I know about arara but afaik latexmk automatically determine correct amount of needed runs. Is this possible with arara?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the corresponding options you would have passed to rubber. To specify output directory it looks like this:

```
rubber-info --check --into build_files thesis.tex
```

where thesis.tex is the input file in the current directory, and build_files is the output directory