# Writting custom rule for arara 4.0

Tags: arara

> Motivation: I would like to copy a file `foo.bar` to `\jobname.bar` before every `pdflatex` run. So I thought, I could modify an existing `arara` rule.

I wanted to try the `hello.yaml` rule for `arara` from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119246/36296

```
!config
# Hello world
# author: Chris Hughes, Paulo Cereda
# last edited by: cmh, June 14th 2013
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
#
# % arara: hello
# % arara: hello: {name: A.Ellett}
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following
#
#   hello
# or
#   hello A.Ellett
#
identifier: hello
name: hello
commands: 
- <arara> bash -i -c hello @{name}
arguments: 
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.name}
  default: "world"
```

But if I try to run this rule with

```
% arara: hello
```

in my `.tex` file, I get the following error message:

> ```
> I have spotted an error in rule 'hello' located at
> '<path to arara>/rules'. I could not parse the rule,
> something bad happened. Apparently, the provided YAML file is
> invalid. I will do my best to help you in any way I can. There
> are more details available on this exception:
>
> DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
> Cannot create property=commands for
> JavaBean=com.github.cereda.arara.model.Rule@55a1c291
>  in
> 'reader', line 1, column 1:
>     !config
>     ^
> No single argument
> constructor found for class
> com.github.cereda.arara.model.RuleCommand
>  in 'reader', line 21,
> column 1:
>     -   <arara> bash -i -c hello @{name}
>     ^
> ```

(I replaced `<path to arara>` in the above message, as the original one contained my user name; I have other custom .yaml files for `arara` in the same location which work flawlessly)

The bash function itself seems to work. If I do

```
bash -i -c hello sam
```

within a terminal, I get

> Hello, sam!

as expected.

I am using `arara 4.0`. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, but can you give me a link to arara v4 installation file for download?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou You can get the source code from https://github.com/cereda/arara and build it yourself from source. You can find some instructions in the readme file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you actually want something like this:

```
!config
# Hello world
# author: Chris Hughes, Paulo Cereda
# last edited by: cmh, June 14th 2013
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
#
# % arara: hello
# % arara: hello: {name: A.Ellett}
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following
#
#   hello
# or
#   hello A.Ellett
#
identifier: hello
name: hello
commands: 
- command: <arara> bash -i -c hello @{name}
arguments: 
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.name}
  default: "world"
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't you want something like this?

```
!config
# Hello world
# author: Chris Hughes, Paulo Cereda
# last edited by: cmh, June 14th 2013
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
#
# % arara: hello
# % arara: hello: {name: A.Ellett}
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following
#
#   hello
# or
#   hello A.Ellett
#
identifier: hello
name: hello
command: <arara> bash -i -c hello @{name}
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.name}
  default: "world"
# vim: set nospell:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! As far as I can see, your solution works perfectly with `arara 3.0`, but unfortunately I do get the same error as above with `arara 4.0`, which I need for my workflow :(

Comment: @samcarter Oh, sorry. I missed that. Where do you get 4.0 from?

Comment: Sorry for hiding this information on the bottom of my question. I compiled version 4.0 from its source: https://github.com/cereda/arara . It has all kinds of fantastic new features, see https://github.com/cereda/arara/wiki/New-feature-highlights-in-4.0. Personally I love the ability to check if some files have changed or if the log contains specific strings to trigger compilations.