# arara: load a local batch script or transform the batch script to an own rule

Tags: automation, scripts, arara

My question is similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119206/is-it-possible-to-write-an-arara-rule-which-uses-a-bash-script), however it has a little different focus. I am working under Windows using MikTeX 2.9.

I do have several `latex` projects which are part of a tool documentation. Each project may create multiple [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) files depending of the number of sub-glossaries used in each document.

```
document.acn
document.glo
document.syg1
document.syg2
...
```

Instead of calling `makeindex` individually on each `glossaries` file with

```
makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.alg -o %maintexname%.acr %maintexname%.acn
makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.glg -o %maintexname%.gls %maintexname%.glo
makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.slg1 -o %maintexname%.syi1 %maintexname%.syg1
makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.slg2 -o %maintexname%.syi2 %maintexname%.syg2
...
```

I wrote a batch script `create_glossaries.cmd` that applies `makeindex` to all `acn`, `glo` and `sygi` files in the main folder of the `latex` project, for acronyms, glossaries and symbols respectively. Thus, I don't really have to know which `glossaries` files are created explicitely and I can use the same batch script for all my documents.

Now I want to switch to build automation with [`arara`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara). I basically got it working to use pdflatex and biber to compile my document. But I am struggeling to include the creation of the glossaries. I could of course input the individual `makeindex` commands for each `glossaries` file with

```
% arara: makeindex: { style: %maintexname%.ist }
```

However, this lacks the generality of the approach and I would have to specify each `glossaries` file for each project. If possible, I'd like to work around that.

So my first solution approach would be to call the batch script from within `arara`. However, I did not really get how to call a batch script, here called `create_glossaries.cmd` from a `arara` rule. How is that possible?

To be platform independent and use the same approach on all operating system supported by `arara` my second question is: How can I extend a rule that does the same as my script, so find each base `glossaries` file and translate it to the proper output using `makeindex`?

And a question related: How can I deliver a possible new `arara` rule in my main `tex` document folder instead of in the `arara` rules path? Background is that the documents are part of a SVN repository, such that I do not know the absolute path where a collaborator checks the `latex` file out to.

---

### Batch script for `makeindex`

This is the file `create_glossaries.cmd`

```
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::
:: Purpose:         Create all glossaries for a tex document
::
:: Conventions:
::
::   - Acronyms:    - Input file extension:     acn*
::                  - Output file extension:    acr*
::                  - Log file extension:       alg*
::
::   - Glossary:    - Input file extension:     glo*
::                  - Output file extension:    gls*
::                  - Log file extension:       glg*
::
::   - Symbols :    - Input file extension:     syg*
::                  - Output file extension:    syi*
::                  - Log file extension:       slg*
::
:: Remarks:         - This script has to be physically present in the tex directory.
::                    A symbolic link does not work.
::
:: Author:          Martin Raedel, DLR-FA-STM, WiMi, 10.02.2016
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::
:: @echo off verhindert Ausgabe Befehlszeilen bis Stapelverarbeitung beendet
@echo off
::
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: set variables - no spaces between variable name and = allowed
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: 
:: manual mode:
::set maintexname=Mixed-Dimensional-Coupling
::
:: automatic mode:
set glo_num=2
::
set glo_input_list[0]=acn
set glo_input_list[1]=glo
set glo_input_list[2]=syg
::
set glo_output_list[0]=acr
set glo_output_list[1]=gls
set glo_output_list[2]=syi
::
set glo_log_list[0]=alg
set glo_log_list[1]=glg
set glo_log_list[2]=slg
::
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: create glossaries
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::
:: Acronyms:
::
::makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.alg -o %maintexname%.acr %maintexname%.acn
::
:: Glossar:
::
::makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.glg -o %maintexname%.gls %maintexname%.glo
::
:: Symbols:
::   manual:
::makeindex -s %maintexname%.ist -t %maintexname%.slg1 -o %maintexname%.syi1 %maintexname%.syg1
::   with automatic symbol input file search
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::
FOR /L %%i IN (0, 1, %glo_num%) DO (
  set inputextension=!glo_input_list[%%i]!
  set outputextension=!glo_output_list[%%i]!
  set logextension=!glo_log_list[%%i]!
  ::echo "inputextension: !inputextension!"
  FOR %%f IN (*.!inputextension!*) DO (
    ::echo %%f
    set fullfilename=%%f
    set filename=%%~nf
    set fileextensionwithdot=%%~xf
    set fileextension=!fileextensionwithdot:~1!
    ::echo "fullfilename: !fullfilename! | fileextension: !fileextension! | !fileextension:~3,1!"
    IF DEFINED fileextension IF "!fileextension:~3,1!"=="" (
      ::echo 3 or less characters
      makeindex -s !filename!.ist -t !filename!.!logextension! -o !filename!.!outputextension! !filename!!fileextensionwithdot! >nul 2>&1
    ) ELSE (
      ::echo more than 3 characters
      set index=!fileextension:~3,1!
      ::echo !index!
      makeindex -s !filename!.ist -t !filename!.!logextension!!index! -o !filename!.!outputextension!!index! !filename!!fileextensionwithdot!>nul 2>&1
    )
  )
)
::
endlocal
```

---

### Solution to idea 1?!

I managed to get the first approach, calling the batch script from an own `arara` rule, working. I added this `araraconfig.yaml` to the main directory of my project.

```
!config
paths:
- '.'
```

to find my own rule-file `create_glossaries.yaml`

```
!config
identifier: create_glossaries
name: create_glossaries
commands: 
- name: Create glossaries
  command: <arara> cmd /c create_glossaries.cmd
arguments: 
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.name}
  default: "create_glossaries"
```

Where the argument is not used, but the file does not work without it.

Comment: Hi! I am in a bit of a hurry, I will take a closer look at your question later on. `:)`

Comment: I am really looking forward to it. Thanks for the great tool. Should I open an issue on Github?

Comment: Hi, deeply sorry for the lack of recent updates. I am drowning with some work of lately, but I will try to tackle this question today. Deeply, deeply sorry... `:(`

Comment: @PauloCereda I know the feeling `;)`. No worries. The initial solution works. There is just the lack of platform independency. I'll add an issue in the `arara` GitHub repo, so this topic won't be forgotten.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not using the `makeglossaries` or `makeglossarieslite` rules?